# How to generate sequence of datetime in Excel according to weekday pattern

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to generate a column of datetime for 1 years according to below pattern. Each cell is filled with a datetime like `18/08/2022 21:00`

1st week pattern:

Mon,Wed,Fri - 09:00, 12:00, 15:00

Tue, Thur - 10:00, 13:00, 16:00

2nd week pattern:

Mon,Wed,Fri - 10:00, 13:00, 16:00

Tue, Thur - 09:00, 12:00, 15:00

Then repeat the same pattern above for remaining weeks respectively until Aug 2023.

How should I generate a column like below?

> `22/08/2022 09:00`
> `22/08/2022 12:00`
> `22/08/2022 15:00`
> `23/08/2022 10:00`
> `23/08/2022 13:00`
> `23/08/2022 16:00`

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are facing? What did you try?

Comment: I created 2 columns. One for the date and one for time. Then concat two column into the 3rd column. But I don't know how to configure the date column to fill down consecutive

Answer (score 1):

Fill a column of cells with an entire iteration of the pattern:

[image]

Then add the following formula for a 2 week cycle:

```
=A1+14
```

and populate down:

[image]